# How to convert DateTime to Eastern Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm trying to create an application that triggers some code when the financial markets are open. Basically in pseudo code:

```
if(9:30AM ET < Time.Now < 4:00PM ET) {//do something}
```

Is there a way I can do this using the DateTime object in C#?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
```

Comment: or anyone else, does this also account for `Eastern Daylight Time`?  Or do you have to detect if DST is on, and then specify which zone to use?

Comment: small addition: use 
DateTime.UtcNow this is what was meant with timeUtc

Comment: `Eastern Standard Time` should handle DST properly.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964894/how-to-convert-time-between-timezones-utc-to-edt

Comment: for the 2nd line, I'd use TimeSpan easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, easternZone).TimeOfDay;
 Then you can easily compare to new TimeSpan(16, 30, 00) etc. :

Comment: If you are using dotnet core or monodevelop and are planing to run that code on linux then use `Ameria/New_York` instad of `Eastern Standard TIme`.

Comment: @TonoNam `Ameria/New_York` is misspelled (just noting it in case somebody else tries to copy and paste like me). Otherwise, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 13):

You could probably use the [ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx) method of the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class to convert a given DateTime to the Eastern timezone and do the comparison from there.

```
var timeToConvert = //whereever you're getting the time from
var est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(timeToConvert, est);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an extension method for it,

NOTE: This is converting the current DateTime to EST

Like this,

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public static DateTime ConvertToEasternTime(this DateTime value)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo tz = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
            ? TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")
            : TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");

        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz);
    }
```

And you can use it like this,

```
EasternTime = DateTime.Now.ConvertToEasternTime(),
```

Just make sure you are importing the namespace to use this method.

NOTE: This below approach is converting the given DateTime to EST

```
    private static TimeZoneInfo GetEasternTimeZoneInfo()
    {
        TimeZoneInfo tz = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
           ? TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")
           : TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");

        return tz;
    }
```

This above method returns the EST TimeZone.

```
    public static DateTime ConvertToEasternTime(DateTime date)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, GetEasternTimeZoneInfo());
    }
```

This above method returns the date that you passed in as a parameter to the EST time

To use the above method we can do,

```
     var convertToEST= DateUtility.ConvertToEasternTime(date);
```

We need to pass the `date` as the argument to convert.
Sometimes we might have to do,

```
     var convertToEST= DateUtility.ConvertToEasternTime(date).Date;
```

Just make sure you are importing the namespace to use this method.

Comment: nice solution, but the `value` is not being used in your example. :)

Answer (score -9):

You need to split up the logic into two;

- Check if date is more than start date, `startTime > now`
- Check if date is less than end date, `endTime < now`

For a date range the logic should satisfy both (with logical AND, `&&`).

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(30);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(12+4);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if(startTime > now && endTime < now) {
    // do something
}
```

If you're in ET timezone it should work fine, but otherwise you need to do some timezone manipulation. Check the other answers.