# How to convert a pandas datetime column from UTC to EST

Tags: python, pandas, time, timezone

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997570/how-to-convert-datetime-to-eastern-time) that is eleven years old with a similar title.

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of datetime.time values.

```
val    time
a      12:30:01.323
b      12:48:04.583
c      14:38:29.162
```

I want to convert the time column from UTC to EST.

I tried to do `dataframe.tz_localize('utc').tz_convert('US/Eastern')` but it gave me the following error: `RangeIndex Object has no attribute tz_localize`

Comment: Can you provide the constructor for your dataframe? i.e. the output of `dataframe.head().to_dict()`

Comment: `{'val': {0: 'a'}, 'time': {0: datetime.time(20, 9, 12, 349211)}}`

Comment: That's a single row. Can you try: `dataframe.head(5).to_dict()`?

Comment: here ya go 

 `{'val': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 'time': {0: datetime.time(20, 9, 12, 349211), 1: datetime.time(20, 9, 13, 435233), 2: datetime.time(20, 9, 14, 345233)}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tz_localize` and `tz_convert` work on the index of the DataFrame. So you can do the following:

1. convert the "time" to Timestamp format
2. set the "time" column as index and use the conversion functions
3. `reset_index()`
4. keep only the time

Try:

```
dataframe["time"] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe["time"],format="%H:%M:%S.%f")
output = (dataframe.set_index("time")
                   .tz_localize("utc")
                   .tz_convert("US/Eastern")
                   .reset_index()
          )
output["time"] = output["time"].dt.time

>>> output
              time val
0  15:13:12.349211   a
1  15:13:13.435233   b
2  15:13:14.345233   c
```

Comment: Got it. It sounds like I can't use pytz.timezone(). Is that right?

Comment: You can if you set the "time" column as the index before you do whatever you need to (i.e `tz_localize`)

Comment: I got an error that says "dataframe has no attribute dt"

Comment: This code works fine with the provided `dataframe` sample.

Comment: "dataframe has no attribute dt" doesn't make sense because not_speshal's code does not have `dataframe.dt` or `output.dt` anywhere, only `output["time"].dt.time` (which tries to use `dt` on a series, not dataframe)

Answer (score 5):

[`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) accepts an argument `utc (bool)` which, when true, coerces the timestamp to utc.

`to_datetime` returns a `DateTimeIndex`, which has a method [`tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_convert.html). this method will convert tz-aware timestamps from one timezeone to another.

So, this transformation could be concisely written as

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
       [['a', '12:30:01.323'],
        ['b', '12:48:04.583'],
        ['c', '14:38:29.162']],
       columns=['val', 'time']
)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, utc=True, format='%H:%M:%S.%f') 
# convert string to timezone aware field ^^^
df['time'] = df.time.dt.tz_convert('EST').dt.time
# convert timezone, discarding the date part ^^^
```

This produces the following dataframe:

```
  val             time
0   a  07:30:01.323000
1   b  07:48:04.583000
2   c  09:38:29.162000
```

This could also be a 1-liner as below:

```py
pd.to_datetime(df.time, utc=True, format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.tz_convert('America/New_York').dt.time
```

Comment: "EST" is not a time zone identifier. Use "America/New_York" in this example. See [list of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 1):

```
list_temp = []
for row in df['time_UTC']:
    list_temp.append(Timestamp(row, tz = 'UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern'))
df['time_EST'] = list_temp
```