# Converting EDT time zone to GMT not working fine in java

Tags: java, timezone

I am using this code to parse this date. It must show new date as **"2012-06-20 03:09:38"** as EDT is -4GMT and my current location is GMT+5. But its not showing this it now showing as it is

```
private static void convertEDT_TO_GMT() {
    try {
        String s = "2012-06-20 18:09:38";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
        Date timestamp = null;

        timestamp = df.parse(s);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:00"));
        System.out.println("Old = " + s);
        String parsed = df.format(timestamp);
        System.out.println("New = " + parsed);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

It show

> Old = 2012-06-20 18:09:38
>
> New = 2012-06-20 23:09:38

Comment: Perhaps you want to read this documentation of Java 7, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html. It says you should use GMT as a reference. EDT, PST, or CST is deprecated.

Comment: [See this answer. You may want getTimeZone("America/New_York")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545960/how-to-tackle-daylight-savings-using-timezone-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The time zone 'EDT' does not exist.  Doing a `System.out.println()` of `TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT") shows that it is falling back to GMT because Java does not know 'EDT' as a time zone.

Changing from `"EDT"` to `"GMT-04:00"` gives the correct result:

```
try {
    String s = "2012-06-20 18:09:38";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    //df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-04:00"));
    Date timestamp = null;

    timestamp = df.parse(s);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:00"));
    System.out.println("Old = " + s);
    String parsed = df.format(timestamp);
    System.out.println("New = " + parsed);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result:

```
Old = 2012-06-20 18:09:38
New = 2012-06-21 03:09:38
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964894/how-to-convert-time-between-timezones-utc-to-edt):

> Eastern Daylight Time isn't the name of a "full" time zone - it's "half" a time zone, effectively, always 4 hours behind UTC.

So using `"GMT-04:00"` might be the right solution.

Comment: I don't usually write thank you comments, but "Thank you".  This was killing me.

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-04:00"));
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("Current EDT Time is : "+date);
```